# Dynamically transposing Rows to Columns (ANSI SQL / Teradata)

Tags: rows, teradata, transpose, ansi-sql

I'm trying to dynamically transpose rows to columns. On the following page (http://forums.teradata.com/forum/analytics/transpose-rows-to-columns-with-1-n-columns) I found a script (from Kirubhakaran) that does something that comes very close.

I'm trying to get the end of month values for a number of accounts as follows (code underneath):

AccountNr, Balance201504, Balance201505, Balance201506

123        1000           1200           900

456        2000           1900

I have the following questions I hope you can help me out with:

- how to adjust this script to my (simpler) needs?
- how can I adjust the script so it does not use the (outdated) CSUM function or may be even better adjust the script so it is ANSI SQL
  compliant?
- how can I run the outcome of this script in Teradata directly (in stead of copy pasting and running it)?

Your help is much appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE EoMBalance
(
 AccountNr int, 
 Mnth varchar(6),
 Balance int
);

INSERT INTO EoMBalance
(AccountNr, Mnth, Balance)
VALUES
(123, '201504', 1000),
(123, '201505', 1200),
(123, '201506', 900),
(456, '201504', 2000),
(456, '201505', 1900);

-- Passive construction of Balance per end of month in columns.-----
SELECT
    AccountNr,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Mnth = '201504' THEN Balance ELSE NULL END) AS Balance201504,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Mnth = '201505' THEN Balance ELSE NULL END) AS Balance201505,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Mnth = '201506' THEN Balance ELSE NULL END) AS Balance201506
FROM
    EoMBalance
GROUP BY
    AccountNr
ORDER BY
    AccountNr
```

Comment: You won't get a better answer than you already got on the DevEx :-) If you actually have to construct the column names including year/month you must use dynamic SQL. For this you need the right to create a Stored Procedure.